User Assigned Device Name entitlement not support app store connect?
we are working on a project to transfer files between iPhone and Android devices over a local network. We need to be able to identify the name of the iPhone device, so we applied for the User Assigned Device Name entitlement. We are pleased that it was approved and that we are able to obtain the correct device name via UIDevice.name. However, the provisioning support only allows Development and Ad Hoc, which seems strange.
How can we get support for App Store Connect?

You need to go into your Apple developer account and add the entitlement to your app identifier. You can then regenerate the provisioning profile you use for the App Store to include the entitlement.
